# Error 42601 de sintaxis en call de procedure postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

```
public string CreatePerson(string name, string pwd, string key)
{
    using (PostgresDbContext db = new PostgresDbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var nameSend = new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("user1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            var pwdSend = new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("password1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            var keySend = new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("key1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
                    
            nameSend.Value = name;
            pwdSend.Value = pwd;
            keySend.Value = key;

            //Aca obtengo el error al llamar el procedure de postgresql. 
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("call dbo.insert_data @user1, @password1, @key1", nameSend, pwdSend, keySend );


            return Constants.Successful;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

El error lo obtengo al hacer el llamado de procedure. El error que me arroja es el siguiente `{"42601: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «$1»"}`. No sé por dónde viene más o menos. Estoy trabajando con:

- EF(entityFramework)
- C#
- y postgresql.

Les agredecería la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

luego de una busqueda y errores tras errores econtre la solucion,
como bien dicen a prueba y errores se logran los exitos. la linea que me ayudo fue esta.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("call dbo.insert_data3(@user1, @password1, @key1)", nameSend, pwdSend, keySend );
```

despues me dio unos errores de ejecucion por permisos lo cual solo le agregue los permisos
correspondientes al usuario de DB,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA dbo TO administradordb;
```